# Passing value between two components in angular2-meteor project

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I am using angular2-meteor.

When I try to pass a value between two components (when the value change in the first component, create an event in second component and use this new value), I have two ways right now:

1. One way is meteor way: using `this.autorun` and `Session.get`.
2. Another way is angular2 way: using `Injectable` service with `EventEmitter`.

Which way should be prior? Or is there any other better way? Thanks

Comment: Angular should be in charge of component to component event communication.  Use those constructs.  EventEmitter is very powerful/flexible.

Comment: @ToddWCrone thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I used angular2-meteor a while.

Although the [angular2-meteor tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping) has no example so far about using or choosing **Angular 2 service** or **Meteor Session**.

But I feel **angular 2** takes the lead in the front end, while **meteor** makes reactivity easier and also handle all back end things.

So I went with angular2 way using service to share between components. And service is very powerful like @todd-w-crone said.

If anyone has better answer, I will switch to accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

I find it practical to create a new service called `App.states.ts` which is accessed globally and mimics Session (get / set).
I commonly import this service to all necessary components to get or set new value such as **User.status, company.profile, lastProduct**, etc.

Since this service is `@injectable` it can also make use of other services, in case a value hasn't been set already.
This allows me to ask for a variable in a component `appState.getLastModifiedItem()`, then in `app.states.ts` I'll write this function to pass `this.modifiedItem` or either:

- Request another service `item.service.ts` to fetch data
- Call another function with `itemCollection.findOne({...})` and return such value.

You can configure Mongo queries as you want and either store static data in `appState` or keep subscription items in appState.

Do take into consideration that all subscriptions handled by an @injectable within a component are imported by such component. Be wary of conflicting subscriptions between components/services.